# How fix warning "Expected to return a value in arrow function array-callback-return"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code:

```
form.listPrice.map(list => {
  if (list.id === listId) {
    form.active = true
    listPrice = parseInt(list.price)
    if (list.offerPrice) {
      listofferPrice = parseInt(list.offerPrice)
    } else {
      listofferPrice = null
    }
  }
})
```

And here:

```
n.listPrice.map(list => {
  if (list.id === listPrice) {
    valid = true;
    n.active = true;
    n.showPrice.price = list.price;
    n.showPrice.offerPrice = list.offerPrice;
    n.ladder = list.ladder;
  }
```

And this output the same warning:

> Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return

Comment: That's the point of the function you pass into [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): it's supposed to turn one thing into another thing. So that function needs to return something, and arrow functions only auto-return _if they're single statements_. If you're using a block scope so you can "run a bunch of code", which you are, you need a `return` keyword at the end of your block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are [using `.map` incorrectly](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/array-callback-return). `.map` should be used only when you want to construct a *new* array from an old array, but your code is not doing that - you're only carrying out side-effects - the setting of `form.active` and `listofferPrice`.

The first step would be to use `forEach` or `for..of` instead, eg:

```
for (const list of form.listPrice) {
    if (list.id === listId) {
        form.active = true
        listPrice = parseInt(list.price)
        if (list.offerPrice) {
            listofferPrice = parseInt(list.offerPrice)
        } else {
            listofferPrice = null
        }
    }
}
```

But since it looks like you're trying to find a possible *single* matching value in the array, `.find` would be more appropriate:

```
const found = form.listPrice.find(list => list.id === listId);
if (found) {
    form.active = true
    listPrice = parseInt(found.price)
    if (found.offerPrice) {
        listofferPrice = parseInt(found.offerPrice)
    } else {
        listofferPrice = null
    }
}
```

```
const found = n.listPrice.find(list => list.id === listPrice);
if (found) {
    valid = true;
    n.active = true;
    n.showPrice.price = found.price;
    n.showPrice.offerPrice = found.offerPrice;
    n.ladder = found.ladder;
}
```

Comment: OMG this has worked perfect for me, thank you very much, it really helped me learn too, another way of looking at it :D!!! I have another question and I would not like to ask another question for this, to see if you can help me, since I saw some things, but I did not understand it very well and it is that I get this warning => Useless constructor no-useless-construct.

I go to the line that indicates me and I have this constructor (props) {
    super (props)
  }

Comment: The constructor isn't doing anything except calling `super`, so it can be removed entirely. See https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-useless-constructor